# Why do I get internal server error with JMeter 5.1?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

I am migrating scripts from version 2.9 to 5.1. One request is failing in both versions sending me this error:

> :internal server error code 500.

What could be the issue?

Comment: If it's failing in both versions it's nothing to do with migration and an issue with the script. Check the server and see whats throwing the 500

Comment: Thank you so much.It's the company's server i don't even know how to check the server errors

Answer (score 0):

Almost each JMeter version contains some incompatible changes, you need to walk through the [JMeter Changelog](https://jmeter.apache.org/changes_history.html), identify all the changes and properly amend your script.

Given [JMeter 2.9 was released in February 2013](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-29-blazemeters-picks-top-two-feature-upgrades/) and now we're in March 2020 I believe it would be easier to [record the tests](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) from scratch as application could change in 7 years hence "old" JMeter scripts are not valid anymore.

With regards to [HTTP Status Code 500](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/500)

> The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) `500 Internal Server Error` server error response code indicates that the server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.
>
> This error response is a generic "catch-all" response. Usually, this indicates the server cannot find a better 5xx error code to response. Sometimes, server administrators log error responses like the 500 status code with more details about the request to prevent the error from happening again in the future.

So you need to look into your server logs, most probably you will get the clue regarding what went wrong from them.

Comment: i will look at the changelog i was just confused because the person training me says it should work well in 5.1 which kind of confused me.I am new to the tool